# ReadItemAsync vs GetItemLinqQueryable?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Has anyone done any profiling on these two methods for retrieving a single object from a CosmosDB?

```
container.ReadItemAsync<Device>("devices", new PartitionKey(deviceId), null, default);
```

VS

```
container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Device>(true).Where(a => a.DeviceId == deviceId).FirstOrDefault();
```

My guess is ReadItemAsync is faster, but does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReadItemAsync is not only faster, but cheaper.

ReadItem does a point read operation, with a fixed amount of [RUs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) (Request Units) based on the size of the item. The operation will always consume the same RUs if the item size does not vary.

ItemLinqQueryable does a query, which will consume more RUs (and these can vary), and it depends on the indexing policy configured.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I am new to cosmos and was wondering why my direct query (where I use readItemAsync generate less RU vs itemLinqQuery generate more RU). Thanks for this detail.

Answer (score 1):

[ReadItemAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.readitemasync?view=azure-dotnet) actually reads and deserializes your JSON into a strongly typed C# object. If you are modifying documents as part of your backend business logic then this makes the most sense to use.

Whereas GetItemLinqQueryable actually does a query which goes through the collection and will cost more RUs compared to ReadItemAsync